Outlook for Salesforce - Event Record Type
What determines the record type an Event will be logged when created from the Salesforce side panel in Outlook? Currently, we have users reporting that the events are created with a different record type than what they have as the default on. If it is not the profile that determines the record type of the generated record then what it is?
